# Getting loss (binary_crossentropy) stagnated around 0.601 for this autoencoder architecture

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, unsupervised-learning

I am working on an unsupervised image classification problem, the dataset consists of around 4700 photos of carnivores. I thought of achieving this task by constructing an autoencoder and getting the image embeddings, then applying cosine similarity. I am not getting much improvement. This is my autoencoder architecture:

```py
Model: "functional_75"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)        [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_126 (Conv2D)          (None, 128, 128, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_54 (MaxPooling (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_127 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_55 (MaxPooling (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_128 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 16)        4624      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_56 (MaxPooling (None, 16, 16, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_129 (Conv2D)          (None, 16, 16, 16)        2320      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_54 (UpSampling (None, 32, 32, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_130 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 32, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_55 (UpSampling (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_131 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_132 (Conv2D)          (None, 64, 64, 3)         1731      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_56 (UpSampling (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 52,067
Trainable params: 52,067
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Please suggest some tips for improvement.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on methods of normalisation/data augmentation you may or may not have used? What does your validation loss look like?

Comment: For normalization I just divided by 255, none augmentation done as all images are centered.